# Euler's paper 'De formulis exponentialibus replicatis' in English

Tags: tetration, translation-request

Is there an English version of this paper of Euler's: [De formulis exponentialibus replicatis](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1488&context=euler-works)?
I can not find one on [Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org) or by internet search.

Comment: Just to confirm, you need a translation of it, not just a presentation of its main result(s) or confirmation of what a particular line says, right?

Comment: @MarkS. Correct.

Comment: May help to mention that this was published in 1778 and is Eneström number 489.